# Chrome extension css inject: Floating button doesn't show

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I am making a Chrome extension that shows a floating button on specific page.
I have used code from w3school (https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_scroll_to_top.asp)
I can see my css is injected into targeted web pages, but floating button doesn't show up.

My code is this:

manifest.json

```
"permissions": [
    "activeTab",
  "tabs",
    "scripting"
],
"host_permissions": [
        "<all_urls>"
],
 "content_scripts": [
   {
    "matches": [
      "https://example.com"
    ],
    "js": ["contentscript.js"],
    "css": ["stbButton.css"]
   }
  ]
```

stbButton.html

```
<button onclick="bottomFunction()" id="stb" title="Go to Bottom">Top</button>
```

stbButton.css

```
body{
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size:18px;
    background-color:#CCC;
}

#stb {
    display: block; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Fixed/sticky position */
    bottom: 20px; /* Place the button at the bottom of the page */
    right: 30px; /* Place the button 30px from the right */
    z-index: 1000009; /* Make sure it does not overlap */
    border: none; /* Remove borders */
    outline: none; /* Remove outline */
    background-color: red; /* Set a background color */
    color: white; /* Text color */
    cursor: pointer; /* Add a mouse pointer on hover */
    padding: 15px; /* Some padding */
    border-radius: 10px; /* Rounded corners */
    font-size: 18px; /* Increase font size */
  }
  
#stb:hover {
    background-color: #555; /* Add a dark-grey background on hover */
}
```

contentscript.js

```
var sb = document.getElementById("stb");

function bottomFunction() {
    document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
}
```

(Yeah, I know it's scroll to top, not bottom, but my priority is showing the floating button. I can fix my code later.)

When I load this extension and go to example.com, I can confirm that my css in injected because the background is all grey(because of stbButton.css's body.style.background-color setting). However, the floating button is nowhere to be seen.

What can be my problem? Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: You need to add the button into the web page explicitly. In this case since the html is simple it's best to access DOM directly: e.g. document.createElement, document.body.appendChild, etc.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank for the answer! I am now reading about createElement and appendChild. 
I tried adding `document.body.appendChild(sb);` to contentscript.js, but nothing happens. What am I possibly missing now?

Comment: You need to create the button first, then append it. You can't use getElementById on a non-existent thing.

Comment: @wOxxOm Always super thanks. Sorted out the issue!